Can I test if a difference for a single subject is large enough to consider that subject an outlier from a population of subjects?
I have measurements of vegetation bed size for four beds before and after an event. Three of the beds are unaffected by the event and all changed in size. One of the beds may have been affected by the event. Can I explore whether the changes at the affected bed lie outside of an expected change over time based on the three unaffected beds? If so, how? I have tried pooling sums of squares for the differences to determine a standard error. If my point lies within some range would that be correct to conclude it is "within the variation in bed size of the unaffected beds"?

Would you be able to specify what you mean by "within the variation in bed size of the unaffected beds"?

If the initial bed sizes were 2,3,4 m2 and the post-event bed sizes were 3,4,5 m2 (beds A, B, and C respectively), each bed has increased by 1 m2. The question is then, if the affected bed went from 3 to 6 is that likely to be considered an outlier? For example, is it outside of a 95% confidence interval? Does that help clarify?

Sorry, I updated my comment to clarify as I realised that might be the question.
